# How do I remove globals from Flask API calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, global-variables

I am working on a Flask application that will run a `Foo`. Once a `Foo` is running, it should be possible to hit endpoints at `hostname:8080` to perform some API call that changes the state of the `Foo`.

Below is a fairly minimal (though not complete) example. The methods and functions referenced aren't terribly important as the question is about the *global object* whose state is being affected.

```
__foo = None
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/start_foo")
def start_foo():
    return __foo._do_foo_init() or ""

def run_foo(foo, debug=False):
    """
    Entry point for clients to run a foo
    :param foo:
    :return:
    """
    global __foo
    __foo = foo
    t = threading.Thread(target=delayed_registration, args=(foo,))
    t.start()
    app.run(host=hostname, debug=debug, port=8080)
```

When a user calls `run_foo`, she will provide a `Bar`, which is a subclass of `Foo`, but this shouldn't matter.

I was thinking that making the `@app.route` a method of a class and have the `foo` as a member of the class, but I don't know if this is possible within Flask.

Does anyone have recommendations for how to remove the global `__foo` in the above application?

Comment: Did you have a look at [http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/)?

Comment: @code_onkel I think this works well for resources that are created within the context of the application. Since `run_foo` will be accepting a previously created `Foo`, I'm not sure it'll work. I could be misunderstanding its use, though!

Answer (score 1):

In flask you should store application global objects in flask.g ([see the documentation for more information](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g)). It is true that this is "local" to the application, but in flask it should be possible to have multiple application in the same python interpreter. The flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-application-context) states:

> Since one of the pillars of Flask’s design is that you can have more than one application in the same Python process.

So everything besides configuration should not be global but local to the flask application.

Comment: I'll give this a go in a bit. Will report back once I've played with it a bit. Have an upvote in the meantime!

Comment: I'm not really sure how flask proxies interact with threads so there might be a problem there. But I guess that also depends on what exactly you are doing in delayed_registration.